# Cannot get clean URL from database - encoding issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this bit of code in my script that creates a link to a PDF.

```
$pdf_filename = $row["outgoing_pdf"];
$pdf_url = rtrim( "http://45.63.20.147/p3/" ) . $pdf_filename;
$pdf_meta = array( $outgoing_pdf , $pdf_url );
```

Then it inserts the PDF using this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id , "ptb_outgoing_pdf" , $pdf_meta );
```

However, in my database, I am getting this

```
a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;s:67:"http://45.63.20.147/p3/pdf/responses/76699168_ROA20100603173238.pdf";}
```

I have been reading for weeks on how to get just the URL from that, but cannot figure it out. I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Answer (score 1):

```
a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;s:67:"http://45.63.20.147/p3/pdf/responses/76699168_ROA20100603173238.pdf";}
```

This is serialized value by `serialize()` function. Use `unserialize()` function to restore original value.

Example - http://ideone.com/zwrO9s

Comment: Its asking for a string, array given

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution.

```
$pdf_filename = $row["outgoing_pdf"];
$pdf_url = rtrim( "http://45.63.20.147/p3/" ) . $pdf_filename;
$pdf_meta = $pdf_url;
```